Phantom signAllTransactions "Unexpected Error"
Hey I'm trying to let user sign a lot of transactions, basically these transactions are made by user (they insert their wallet addresses/pubkeys), however when im trying to signAllTransactions, with wrong pubkey (i guess it's because of that) it shows me "Unexpected Error" in console on following line: const signedTransactions: Transaction[] = await window.solana.signAllTransactions(transactions), i found the error code for this error is -32603 Internal Error Something went wrong within Phantom. which is not very helpful. Is there any way to debug it, or to let signAllTransactions and just skip unsignable?

I can't find any more info, but I think Phantom had plans to deprecate signAllTransactions
